# Tasks in Recursion

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a function to traverse a binary tree recursively. As the operations are compute intensive I thought of spawning multiple threads in the recursive function using tasks as follows:

```
static void Traverse<T>(Tree<T> node, Action<T> action) 
{ 
 if (node == null) return; 
 var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action(node.Data)); 
 var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Traverse(node.Left, action)); 
 var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Traverse(node.Right, action)); 
 Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3); 
}
```

Now this does seem to work. However I want to know if there is anything I need to be careful about while using tasks in recursive fashion. E.g if the depth of the tree is long could it somehow not able to create tasks for lower levels and wait for other tasks to finish (which would never finish as they are waiting for lower level tasks to finish)?

Comment: Error in your code, Traverse needs to be `Action<Tree<T>>`, your code won't compile as is as you are passing `Tree<T>`  into `action(node)` but it is expecting just `T`.

Comment: Thanks Scott for pointing I out. Corrected the code. I made some changes to simplify it for the question and introduced the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tree is very large spawning that many tasks could cause problems completely exhausting the entire thread pool causing performance problems elsewhere, this is because there is no dependency between the nodes and their parents so all will attempt to run concurrently. What I would do is have your `Tree<T>` class implement `IEnumerable<T>` that will return it's own `Data` property and all it's children's `Data` properties then use [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
static void Traverse<T>(Tree<T> node, Action<T> action) 
{
    Parallel.ForEach(node, action);
}


//Elsewhere
class Tree<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    Tree<T> Left { get; set; }
    Tree<T> Right { get; set; } 
    T Data { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this.Data;

        if (Left != null)
        {
            foreach (var left in Left)
            {
                yield return left.Data;
            }
        }

        if (Right != null)
        {
            foreach (var right in Right)
            {
                yield return right.Data;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The only "Gotcha" you need to concern yourself with is if there are any closed loops in the tree where a child could be the parent of a higher level node which would cause infinite recursion.

---

**EDIT**: Here is a new version that does not use recursion on the `GetEnumerator` and instead uses a `Stack<Tree<T>>` object to hold the state so if you had ***extremely*** tall trees you can't have a `StackOverflowException`. Also if you remove the comments from the commented lines it will stop the "infinite recursion" problem that the previous version had. But if you know you won't have any looping structures it is not necessary, so I left it commented out.

```
class Tree<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    Tree<T> Left { get; set; }
    Tree<T> Right { get; set; }
    T Data { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Stack<Tree<T>> items = new Stack<Tree<T>>();
        //HashSet<Tree<T>> recursiveCheck = new HashSet<Tree<T>>();

        items.Push(this);
        //recursiveCheck.Add(this);

        while (items.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = items.Pop();

            yield return current.Data;

            if (current.Left != null)
                //if(recursiveCheck.Add(current.Left))
                    items.Push(current.Left);
            if (current.Right != null)
                //if (recursiveCheck.Add(current.Right))
                    items.Push(current.Right);
        }

    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. Using an enumerator does make sense.

Comment: “completely exhausting the entire thread pool” Wouldn't task inlining avoid that issue?

Comment: @svick I don't know, possibly.

Comment: @svick you do have a point. I tested the tree with max concurrency of 2 and a depth of 20 and I can clearly see it uses the same thread for multiple tasks inlining it in the parents thread. Nevertheless I still feel I should go with the enumerator approach that Scott suggested to avoid any other issues I might overlook using recursion.

Answer (score -1):

Like you said, spawning threads recursively doesn't seem to be a good idea and if your tree is long enough you'll end up with either lots of thread which will be slower because there will be lots of overheads, or you'll eventually hit the limit of parallel threads in your program. So I suggest you use a ThreadPool instead to manage your threads.

You may have one thread to navigate the tree, and another two threads to do the heavy work. You should also note that using thread won't be good unless you have some blocking operations like I/O read/write or some networking going on. If you don't, it's probably best to use only one thread for your heavy work and one for traversing the tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i think Task.StartNew() uses thread pool threads

Answer (score -1):

I do not think that it would stop working at any point, but the use of multiple threads can increase CPU usage as the computer is doing more operations at once so it may be safer, yet slower, to not use multiple threads and just use the following:

```cs
static void Traverse<T>(Tree<T> node, Action<T> action)
{
 if (node == null) return;
 action(node);
 Traverse(node.Left, action);
 Traverse(node.Right, action);
}
```

This will be slower though so if you are worried about how fast it runs you will want to use your original version.

Comment: What do you mean by “safer”? How is *not* using all of the available CPU a good thing?

Comment: If you use more of the CPU it can cause extreme lag throughout your computer and can also with extremely large trees cause your hard drive to begin to overheat, but that is only when it gets _extremely_ CPU intensive.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The lag that you describe can happen when you have an application that's very *memory-intensive*, it won't happen with application that just use a lot of CPU (assuming that application doesn't have high priority). And CPU usage certainly doesn't have anything to do with the hard drive.